# NetTopologySuite.Geometries.MultiPoint needs to have a constructor with 0 args

Tags: c#, automapper, nettopologysuite

I'm trying to map a [NetTopologySuite.Geometries.MultiPoint](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/blob/b58b842ad2506e97188fee804a3135935ceae7b8/src/NetTopologySuite/Geometries/MultiPoint.cs) with Automapper but I keep getting the error `System.ArgumentException: NetTopologySuite.Geometries.MultiPoint needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args`.

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
     
MultiPoint mp1 = null;
MultiPoint mp2 = mapper.Map<MultiPoint>(mp1); // throws
```

Indeed, this type doesn't have a constructor with 0 arguments. I've tried specifying how to instantiate the type:

```cs
new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<MultiPoint, MultiPoint>()
        .ConstructUsing(mp => new MultiPoint((Point[])mp.Geometries));
});
```

Same error. To reproduce with a simpler code, I created a class with no 0 args constructor.

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { });
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

TestCollection tc1 = null;
TestCollection tc2 = mapper.Map<TestCollection>(tc1); // throws

class Test
{
}

class TestCollection : IEnumerable<Test>
{
    public TestCollection(Test[] tests) => Tests = tests;
    public Test[] Tests { get; set; }
    public IEnumerator<Test> GetEnumerator() => new TestCollectionEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}

class TestCollectionEnumerator : IEnumerator<Test>
{
    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;
    public Test Current { get; }
    public bool MoveNext() => false;
    public void Reset() { }
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: The full code is in the first snippet. The same snippet in a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m8Lktd).

Comment: I think I'm using the latest version here (10.1.1)

Comment: I've updated the question with a repro without `MultiPoint`.

Comment: Well, yes, but you do need the map and the `ConstructUsing` :) And you cannot map smth both as a collection and a POCO at the same time. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Is it expected? Is there any alternative? Looking at the execution plan, it is not clear where it throws. In does contain a `                $typeMapDestination = ($dest ?? .New A.TestCollection(.Call System.Array.Empty()));` which means the `ConstructUsing` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your MultiPoint is null. With Nettopologysuite the multipoint (points inside can't be null).

```
MultiPoint mp1 = null;
```

To

```
MultiPoint mp1 = NetTopologySuite.Geometries.MultiPoint.Empty;
```

Comment: In the end I've used `MultiPoint.Empty` but I don't get why null isn't mapped to null.